# Xshell: Unable to login to virtual VM using ssh

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I have a Virtual VM RHEL9. Also configured port forwarding to login to m/c using ssh.

When i am using cmd [in Win11] it works fine.

[ssh using cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heGfj.png)

But the same fails when used in xshell

[ssh using xshell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwYDX.png)

I am not sure what configuration needed on xshell to fix this. Also why its only using port 22 even though mentioning -p 2323

Pls suggest.